# Should I recreate the whole socket when a server was rebooted and client received WSAECONNRESET error code

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, winsock

Should I recreate the whole socket when a server was rebooted and client received `WSAECONNRESET` error code on the last call to `send` function? It seems that I am unable to just call the `connect` function on the same socket again -- it will fail with `WSAEISCONN` error code over and over again. Am I need to call `closesocket` and create `SOCKET` again with the `socket` function then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a socket connection has been disconnected, you must close the `SOCKET` handle and create a new one. The only exception to this is if you use [`DisconnectEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737757.aspx) with the `TF_REUSE_SOCKET` flag, then the `SOCKET` can be reused with [`ConnectEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606.aspx) or [`AcceptEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737524.aspx).

Comment: Is there any documentation about it?

Comment: Did you look at the links that are in my answer?

Comment: I mean is there any documentation that I can't just call connect function after server was rebooted?

Comment: The [`connect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625.aspx) documentation says: "*Any attempt to reconnect an active connection will fail with the error code WSAEISCONN.*".

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what does it mean by an active connection? It was closed on the server-side, wasn't it?

Comment: yes, but the socket is still open and bound on the client side until it is closed. Once closed, it cannot be reused. There is a difference between being disconnected and being closed.